# I have problems with understanding how to pivot a dataframe with pandas correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I'm fairly new to pandas and have been trying to understand how to pivot this data frame.

```
                         rootID   parentID    jobID  time
                      0    A         A          B    2019-01-30 14:33:21.339469
                      1    A         B          C    2019-01-30 14:33:21.812381
                      2    A         C          D    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381
                      3    E         E          F    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381
                      4    E         F          G    2019-01-30 16:33:21.812381
```

Into a frame like this

```
                         rootID   subID1      subID2   subID3 
                      0    A         B          C        D    
                      1    E         F          G
```

Is there any way to use the pd.pivot function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new column, then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), change column names by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), replace missing values and lastly [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index:

```
df1 = (df.assign(g=df.groupby('rootID').cumcount().add(1))
         .pivot('rootID','g','jobID')
         .add_prefix('subID')
         .fillna('')
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
g rootID subID1 subID2 subID3
0      A      B      C      D
1      E      F      G
```

Comment: So this works perfectly, but what is it that the line actually does? First it groups the frame by the rootID. What does the cumcount().add(1) do?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to add another column which is the difference between the the root time and subID time? Such as time(A) - time(D) in the first row.

Comment: @Kspr - Sure, if check `print (df.assign(g=df.groupby('rootID').cumcount().add(1)))` it create counter column by duplicated `rootID`. This column is used for new columns names in pivot function.

Comment: @Kspr - Not sure if understand, after pivot is lost this information in this column. What is expected output ? Because there is one `rootID` and multiple `subID`

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. Is it possible to add a column which tells us how many subID each rootID has? Such that the first row would have 3 and second round 2?

Comment: @Kspr - Yes, simpliest is `df['Count'] = (df != '').sum(axis=1).astype(int).sub(1)`

Comment: I noticed that a problem which I had not though about before arised with this. I put up another question regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590064/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-with-pandas-correctly

Comment: @Kspr - Can you explain more? I dont understand output.

Comment: One parentID/rootID can have several branches of subIDs. I want to have one row per branch. Does that clarify it?